# Problem detecting Wifi on Asus A74A with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, wireless, dual-boot, windows-8, asus

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 13.04 as double boot with Windows 8 into my new Asus X74A. Everything works fine, expect the Wifi! although it recognizes the ESSID (see below), it does not switch it **ON**. Note that under Windows 8 it works fine.

```
eth0     no wireless extensions.

lo       no wireless extensions.

wlan0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
              Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
              Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
              Power Management:of
```

Any help!

---

```
prgenevo@prgenevo-X75A1:~$ sudo lshw -class NETWORK
*-network DÉSACTIVÉ     
   description: Interface réseau sans fil
   produit: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
   fabriquant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   identifiant matériel: 0
   information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
   nom logique: wlan0
   version: 01
   numéro de série: 20:68:9d:98:4d:55
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.8.0-19-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   ressources: irq:17 portE/S:e000(taille=256) mémoire:f7d00000-f7d03fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   produit: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
   fabriquant: Qualcomm Atheros
   identifiant matériel: 0
   information bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
   nom logique: eth0
   version: 10
   numéro de série: 08:60:6e:95:8d:9a
   taille: 100Mbit/s
   capacité: 1Gbit/s
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=1.2.3 duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.18 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   ressources: irq:19 mémoire:f7c00000-f7c3ffff portE/S:d000(taille=128)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct driver loaded for your device but it is problematic in ubuntu sometimes adding driver parameters help if not compiling the latest driver is usually the only way to get it to work.

Please do:

```
echo "options rtl8192ce swenc=1 ips=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192ce.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rtl8192ce
sudo modprobe -v rtl8192ce
```

Edit:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8192ce 
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo modprobe rtl8192ce
```

Edit:
If you have windows installed make sure wireless is on in window before you boot ubuntu.

Also go into bios and make sure wireless is enabled if you have that option in the bios if not reset the bios.

Edit:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

add the following three lines:

```
rmmod -f rtl8192ce
rfkill unblock all
modprobe rtl8192ce
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. 
Reboot

Comment: did not work details are shown above

Comment: @veliba Please don't edit an answer with your "results". You can post your results on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and add a comment with the link here. Please see http://askubuntu.com/about and http://askubuntu.com/help (you will be rewarded with a badge if you will do this :) )

Comment: @veliba For example: *It did not work; I got the same results: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6093471/*. It's not so hard!

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.

Comment: Here is the link  http://pastebin.com/a0YZtG02

Comment: It says it is hardblocked that usually means the physical switch is off, it may be a slide or push button switch, or a key combination like FN+ F2.

Comment: There is no physical switch on the Asus X75A. When I boot in Windows 8 it is always on and then the. Fn F2 serves has a switch. When I boot Ubuntu, with a wifi that was previously on in W8 (little green light), it never show up under Ubuntu, even if I switch with the Fn F2.

Comment: Press FN+F2 then run `rfkill list all` does the hardblock say no and softblock say no? If not do the above one more time. If it still does not work follow the last commands I am about to add to the answer.

Comment: still does not work: soft blocked: no hard blocked: yes

Comment: did not work either still hard blocked...

Comment: That is the last thing that I know to try in the answer I just edited.

Comment: still does not work... W8 is giving me and my wifi a hard time. I ll go one tomorrow. thanks for you help.

Answer (score -1):

Just try to activate the interface:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

and

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower on
```

EDIT:
According to the output you should be using a Realtek RTL8188CE.

You can try using that driver (you can find the driver here: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8188CE ) you have to download the "Linux kernel 2.6.24 or later".

So do this:

1. Download the driver
2. Uncompress the archive: `tar -jxvf linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013.tar.bz2`
3. Install build-essential and kernel headers (or you won't be able to compile): `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
4. Use the README file inside the archive to compile & install the driver

Anyway the installation process should be:
    su -
    cd *DRIVER_DIRECTORY* (it should be "rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013"
    make
    make install
    reboot

But as I said, read the README file inside the driver archive to being sure.

Comment: This answer is confusing to new users. Please provide commands with sudo prefix to avoid confusion. For example say open a terminal by pressing **Ctrl+Alt+T** and enter each line separately and provide your password when prompted: `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` and `sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower on`

Comment: Does not work because  SIOCSIFFLAGS: impossible because of RF-kill

Comment: Do a sudo "sudo rfkill list" and see if you wifi card is soft-blocked (you can see this in the "Soft blocked line").
If yes, this means that your wifi card has been switched off by the kernel; so run a "sudo rfkill unblock wifi && sudo rfkill unblock all" to unlock it.
You can now do "sudo rfkill list" again just to check that it's now unlocked. Now the wifi card should work, if not and "iwconfig" keep showing you Tx-Power=off just run the two lines I wrote in the answer, you should now be able to turn the wifi radio on.

Comment: Did nid work got:prgenevo@prgenevo-X75A1:~$ sudo rfkill list 
[sudo] password for prgenevo: 
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
prgenevo@prgenevo-X75A1:~$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Opération impossible du fait de RF-kill
prgenevo@prgenevo-X75A1:~$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Opération impossible du fait de RF-kill
prgenevo@prgenevo-X75A1:~$

Comment: So try `sudo rfkill unblock all` and be sure that your wifi card is  activated on the laptop switch

Comment: I have no laptop switch except fn F2, which does not give any signal. I have tried the following without success, again because of RF-kill.

Comment: prgenevo@prgenevo-X75A1:~$ sudo rfkill unblock all[sudo] password for prgenevo: prgenevo@prgenevo-X75A1:~$ sudo rfkill list0: phy0: Wireless LANSoft blocked: noHard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: WirelessLANSoft blocked: noHard blocked: noprgenevo@prgenevo-X75A1:~$ iwconfig
eth0 no wireless extensions.
lono wireless extensions.
wlan0 IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off  Retry  long limit:7  RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off Power Management:on prgenevo@prgenevo-X75A1:~$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Opération impossible du fait de RF-kill

Comment: Are you sure that FN+F2 makes any difference? Try `sudo rfkill list` first and after FN+F2 and see if anything changes. If nothing happens, add the output of `sudo lshw -class NETWORK` in your question

Comment: nothing happened with FN+F2

Comment: results of sudo lshw class NETWORK is above in the answer sexion

Comment: @velibra You should not add additional info in the answer section. You should edit your question instead.

Comment: I edited my answer